# Are Windows executables forward and backwards compatible?

Tags: c++, windows-10, portable-executable

Say I'm building a C++ portable executable and I include the windows.h header.  Also, let's stick to just Windows 10.  If I use the most recent Windows 10 Visual C++ toolchain to build the binary, can I run the binary on earlier versions of Windows 10?  If I use the earliest Windows 10 Visual C++ toolchain to build the binary, can I run it on the latest version of Windows 10?

Let me know if you would like me to clarify the question.

Comment: No, Windows executables are not forward and backwards compatible.  For example, Windows 7 has different features (and safety features) than Windows 3.1.  Windows 10 has different capabilities than Windows 8 or Windows 7.  A lot of Windows 3.x are deprecated.  As far as future compatibility is concerned, that depends on Microsoft.  An executable that takes advantage of Windows 10 features will not run on Windows 3.x.

Comment: As far as portability is concerned, be aware that not all PCs have the same hardware, which makes portability a bit more difficult.  You may have to go the Linux route and have the client build the executable on their machine from the source code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: That's not a matter of the binaries, but of the libraries and APIs they use. A win3.1 executable that *doesn't* use APIs that have been removed would still be valid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ThomasMatthews.  However, both responses are not within the scope of the question.  I specifically ask about backwards and forwards compatibility of PE binaries targeted for Windows 10, within Windows 10.

Comment: If I compile my code targeting the current generation Intel processor, it (probably) won't run on an earlier generation processor that does not have that feature.  So if my code depends on having SSE through SSE4.2, it (probably) won't run on CPU that does not have SSE3 or later.

Comment: which toolchain you use not play role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from Microsoft's documentation under [Update WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=msvc-160).

> *Visual Studio and the Microsoft C++ compiler support targeting Windows 7 SP1 and later.*
>
> *Older toolsets include support for Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2003 SP1, Vista, and Windows Server 2008.*
>
> *Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows ME, Windows NT, and Windows 2000 are unsupported.*

Applications targeted at Windows 10 with the default `#define`'s will run under all versions of Windows 10.

```
    #define WINVER       0x0A00
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
```

To use newer APIs introduced in a later version of Windows 10, see the section under Remarks starting with "*for a more fine-grained approach to versioning, you can use the NTDDI version constants in sdkddkver.h*", and also the [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/WinProg/using-the-windows-headers#macros-for-conditional-declarations) page. For example, compiling with `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00` and `#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WIN10_19H1` will allow using features introduced in Windows 10 19H1, but only targets Windows 10 19H1 and later.

Comment: Thanks! This is just to reach the minimum character limit.

Comment: Microsoft really painted themselves into a corner with the current Windows naming scheme.  There's no good way to know which version of Windows 10 is compatible with another.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's always been a problem since 95 OSR2, 98 SE, NT4 SP6a and so on ;-)

Comment: But at least you could count on someday having a clear delineation when Microsoft bumped the major version; Windows 7 was clearly different from Windows XP.  But they've stated that Windows 10 will be 10 forever.

Comment: all this not related on which versions applications will be run. set this macros only affect which declarations in *.h* files will be visible.

Comment: @RbMm Right, that's entirely correct. The actual version compatiblity depends on the combination of source code, build toolset, and target sdk/runtimes. My answer simplified much of that given the context of OP's question about the latest toolset and Win10 targeting.

Comment: from build toolset this not depend at all. really all depend from what api we import (direct or indirect say via crt). also possible set minimum system version in optional header.

Comment: @RbMm What I meant is that, for example, it's not (officially) possible to build an XP-compatible app with the latest v142 toolset, and not sure it's technically possible to build a 98-compatible app with it.

Comment: very easy build xp-compatibility app with this (if not use *crt* at all or from this toolset) the 98 - by fact another os. not windows **nt**.